# PS4 controller don't charge or turns on (even when connected to ps4)

Tags: ps4, controllers

I couldn't find any solution through the internet. My controller isn't charging or turning on even when connected to ps4. I've already changed the micro USB port and tested another battery and nothing. I placed a charged battery in it, and when i pressed the ps button, only a blue light appeared for a few seconds, and then the controller just turned off again. Is there any solution, or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Sounds like something might be disconnected on the board. I suggest taking it in to a repair shop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the cable that connects to the USB port and main board? I found out one of my controllers was charging with a red light and I replaced the USB port also but the issue was still present. I replaced the ribbon cable and that solved the issue. It had a minor konk in it. You can also try holding down the share and PS button for a few seconds to get the longer bluetooth signal to connect to your ps4.